# Count frequency of words and string

Tags: python

I need to count number of words in sentence. I do it with

```
word_matrix[i][j] = sentences[i].count([*words_dict][j])
```

But it also counts when a word is included in other word, for example 'in' is included in 'interactive'. How to avoid it?

Comment: Please provide full code together with sample data. Most probably you're doing it in inefficient way.

Comment: `word_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(n, d))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(d):
        word_matrix[i][j] = sentences[i].count([*words_dict][j])`

Comment: I try to get matrix, where element [i][j] means number of j element in i sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this:

```
from collections import Counter
s = 'This is a sentence'

Counter(s.lower().split())

# Counter({'this': 1, 'is': 1, 'a': 1, 'sentence': 1})
```

Comment: I don't think counter is the most efficient way to do this

Comment: No its not if the purpose is to only count the amount of words, which is a very trivial task. From what I've posted I've obviously understood counting in the sense of word count. I might have missunderstood.

Comment: It is more efficient to use len() on the array returned by the split() function as this is a built in function and no import is required.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. As I've already stated the purpose of using `Count` is not to count how many words, but rather how many times each word occurs....

Comment: And from what OP has posted, I suspect that is what he wants. Again I might be wrong. So if you dowvoted me because my attempt was to obtain the same as in your solution I'll point out that your downvote is unjustified, as the question is ambiguous, and I clearly interpreted something else than you did

Comment: Ok. I'm. not sure that's what the question was asking for though

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
sentence = 'this is a test sentence'
word_count = len(sentence.split(' '))
```

in this case word_count would be 5.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, the most efficient solution would be using `collection.Counter`, but you will miss all the words with a symbol:
i.e.  `in` will be different from `interactive` (as you want), but will also be different from `in:`.
An alternative solution that consider this problem could be counting the matched pattern of a RegEx:

```
import re

my_count = re.findall(r"(?:\s|^)({0})(?:[\s$\.,;:])".format([*words_dict][j]), sentences[i])
print(len(my_count))
```

**What is the RegEx doing?**
For a given word, you match:
the same word preceded by a space or start of line `(\s|^)`
and followed by a space, end of the line, a dot, comma, and any symbol in the square brackets (`[\s$\.,;:]`)

Answer (score 0):

use split to tokenise the words of statement, then use logic if word exist in dict then increment the value by one otherwise add the word with count as one :

```
paragraph='Nory was a Catholic because her mother was a Catholic, and Nory’s mother was a Catholic because her father was a Catholic, and her father was a Catholic because his mother was a Catholic, or had been' 
words=paragraph.split()
word_count={}
counter=0
for i in words:
    if i in word_count:
        word_count[i]+=1
    else:
        word_count[i]=1

print(word_count)
```